# ItemsSource Property did not updated in Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, dependency-properties

Hi I have use the following Code snippet to create custom control for generating multiple Menuitems and it is the code snippet of example to explain my working scenorio

**Generic XAML**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
                    </Menu>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The following code snippet i have created the DependencyProperty in CustomControl

```
    public class CustomControl1 : Control
    {
        static CustomControl1()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
        }

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(CustomControl1), new PropertyMetadata(0));    
}
```

And also i have intizialize this custom control in my xaml part like below code snippet

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:CustomLib="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <CustomLib:CustomControl1 Name="CustomControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have created the ListItems in MainWindows.xaml.cs file and also define the DataContext as this.DataContex as this like below code snippet

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            CreateListItems();
        }

        private void CreateListItems()
        {
            this.ListItems = new List<MenuModel>();
            this.ListItems.Add(new MenuModel() { Header = "Test1" });
            this.ListItems.Add(new MenuModel() { Header = "Test2" });
            this.ListItems.Add(new MenuModel() { Header = "Test3" });
        }

        private List<MenuModel> listItems;
        public List<MenuModel> ListItems
        {
            get
            {
                return listItems;
            }
            set
            {
                listItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ListItems");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);

                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ListItems.Add(new MenuModel() { Header = "Test4" });
            this.CustomControl.ItemsSource = this.ListItems;
        }
    }

    public class MenuModel
    {
        public string Header
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

While add button click i have change the ItemsSource but it is not updated. Can you please help me how to achieve this

Comment: public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(CustomControl1), new PropertyMetadata(**0**));  Change the last parameter to null.

Comment: @Rajasekar did you try using `ObservableCollection<MenuModel>` instead of `List<MenuModel>`?

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1432140/dkozl Thank you for your update i have tried with ObservableCollection and it's working correctly for my working scenorio